# Locking updates to a specific mirror

Tags: package-management, apt, updates, official-repositories

My ISP offers a freezone Ubuntu mirror (http://ftp.iinet.net.au/pub/ubuntu/) however Ubuntu is constantly pulling updates from a US server that is

- slower
- not inside my freezone

How can I force Ubuntu to use my local, freezone mirror before using others?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to the menu System > Administration > Software Sources. There is a drop-down box labled "Download from:" where you can choose a mirror near you.

If this doesn't work as planned (might not since you have a "custom mirror") then you can edit the file `/etc/apt/sources.list` by typing `sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list` in a terminal and pressing enter, if you need help you can type `man sources.list` in the terminal.

A source of the unwanted traffic might be from `security.ubuntu.com` this is where the security updates comes from, they can be turned off, but it's not recommended!

Comment: Thanks. My local freezone mirror is actually officially listed by Ubuntu as an official mirror. Bonus!